# Can'T click textView when delegate is set

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have an App with 2 Views on top of each other and on the overlaying view there is a `UITextView` and a UIButton next to it.
When I click the Button once the TextView should become smaller 
(from `CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 100)` 
to
 `CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 50)`) and on the second click it should become bigger again.
Here's the code how I manage this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    if(counter == 1) {
    [self.textView removeFromSuperview];
    self.textView = nil;
    self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 50)];
    [self.overlayView addSubview:self.textView];
    counter = 2;
    } else {
        [self.textView removeFromSuperview];
        self.textView = nil;
        self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 100)];
        [self.overlayView addSubview:self.textView];
        counter = 1;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I do it like this, I can't handle the delegate methods for the UITextView like `textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView` without setting the delegate. But when I set the delegate like `self.textView.delegate = self` after recreating the TextView, nothing happens when I click on it. No keyboard appears and the events aren't called either.
Any suggestions?

Comment: can you share any picture so we can visualize the problem ?

Comment: There is much more on those views, I just summarized my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to `alloc` your textView in the `ViewDidLoad`,

```
self.textView = [[UITextView alloc]init];

and on the button click use

[self.textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 50)];

and 

[self.textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 100)];
```

Comment: See Akhilrajtr's answer, it's pretty similar and I posted the result I get

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Initialise and `addSubview` `self.textView` in `viewDidLoad` and set `self.textView.delegate = self;`

```
-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    if(counter == 1) {

    self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 50);
    counter = 2;
    } else {

        self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 100);
        counter = 1;
    }
    [self.overlayView bringSubviewToFront:self.textView];
}
```

Just change the frame of `self.textView` in `buttonTouched:`

Comment: When I do it like this, the textView is displayed like in my storyboard(smaller size like the one I draw with CGRect and at another position) and I still can't click it.

Comment: Did you connected `IBOutlet` to textview?

Comment: Is there any other view over the textview or overlayView? Try `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.overlayView];`

Comment: Not that I know. Is there any way to check it?
I implemented Google Admob(on the overlayView) and it messed a few things up earlier but I don't create another view

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    if(counter == 1) {
    [self.textView removeFromSuperview];
    self.textView = nil;
    self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 50)];
    [self.overlayView addSubview:self.textView];
    counter = 2;
    } else {
        [self.textView removeFromSuperview];
        self.textView = nil;
        self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.bounds.size.width, 100)];
        [self.overlayView addSubview:self.textView];
        counter = 1;
    }
}
```

- In above code only change "self.view.bounds.size.width" insted of "self.view.frame.bounds.size.width"
- Assign delegate "self.textView.delegate=self" before that in .h file 
  @interface ViewController : UIViewController

Comment: what is the background color of your overlayView?
check your textview is displayed or not...

Comment: `[UIColor clearColor]`. It is displayed, I see the default text I set for it.

Comment: Yes it is implemented there.

Comment: that's why textview not touchable because, googleadmob default view is front of your textview, and its every time update.

Comment: And how can I fix that?

Comment: use other view for that.

Comment: just checked if it works when I don't add the adView to the overlayView but the result is still the same with the above code.